# Dynamic C# code execution

Tags: c#

I need to run small snippets of C# code for educational purposes and for each execution, I should open the project (solution), delete existing code, type new code, build and compile, and then run the project. For example, for executing `string.IsNullOrEmpty("something")` I should follow all this procedure. 
I just thought of something like:

[image]

In which I can enter code snippets, click execute, and then see the result. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You didn't explicitly state if you're looking for guidance on implementing your own solution or what, but if you're open to using a third party utility then [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is pretty much exactly what you're describing.

Comment: I'm not interested to create my own solution for this. I just want to know if there is any tool out there available or not? Thanks for the link, I'll try that. But it seems that this application only executes LINQ queries. I want something global. Something that can execute one-line expressions like `"Source String".Replace("Source", "Target");`

Comment: You can execute single lines of code in LinqPad, as well as write small programs. I use it frequently for bits and pieces of throw-away code - and only rarely (if ever) for writing Linq2SQL queries. Despite the slightly misleading name, LinqPad does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/).

Not exactly what you're asking for, but from what I can tell it seems pretty close.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want (as it's really complex and puzzles newbies). But it's really close. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is also [ideone](http://ideone.com/) which can run C# code, as well as a large number of other languages.

Comment: Interesting, but it doesn't seem to evaluate expressions - it seems to be just a wrapper around csc.exe.

Answer (score 0):

There is also mono's csharp/gsharp:

see http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl

Answer (score 0):

Mono are doing the compiler as service stuff - this is what you are looking for: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2010/Apr-27.html